# store input data to dimensional array

Tags: php

store html input data to array

here is my html code

```
    <form method="post" >
<ul>
<li>Title: <input type="text" name="item[0][title]" />
    <ul>
    <li>name: <input type="text" name="item[0][data][0][name]" /></li>
    <li>decription: <input type="text" name="item[0][data][0][description]" /></li>
    <li><input type="text" name="item[0][data][0][price][0][size]" /> price: <input type="text" name="item[0][data][0][price][0][price]" /></li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
    <li>name: <input type="text" name="item[0][data][1][name]" /></li>
    <li>decription: <input type="text" name="item[0][data][1][description]" /></li>
    <li>size: <input type="text" name="item[0][data][1][price][0][size]" /> price: <input type="text" name="item[0][data][1][price][0][price]" /></li>
    <li>size: <input type="text" name="item[0][data][1][price][1][size]" /> price: <input type="text" name="item[0][data][1][price][1][price]" /></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
Title: <input type="text" name="item[1][title]" />
    <ul>
    <li>name: <input type="text" name="item[1][data][0][name]" /></li>
    <li>decription: <input type="text" name="item[1][data][0][description]" /></li>
    <li>size: <input type="text" name="item[1][data][0][price][0][size]" /> price: <input type="text" name="item[1][data][0][price][0][price]" /></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li>
Title: <input type="text" name="item[2][title]" />
    <ul>
    <li>name: <input type="text" name="item[2][data][0][name]" /></li>
    <li>decription: <input type="text" name="item[2][data][0][description]" /></li>
    <li>size: <input type="text" name="item[2][data][0][price][0][size]" /> price: <input type="text" name="item[2][data][0][price][0][price]" /></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
<input type="hidden" name="submit" value="haha">
<button>submit</button>
</form>
```

here is the array look like but it's only output half i use var_dump sorry

```
array (size=2)
  'title' => string 'rice' (length=4)
  'data' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        array (size=3)
          'name' => string 'fried rice' (length=10)
          'description' => string 'stir fried white rice' (length=21)
          'price' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
      1 => 
        array (size=3)
          'name' => string 'white rice' (length=10)
          'description' => string '' (length=0)
          'price' => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
```

it's working to save data to array, but the way i use to change attribute name to array format.

i try to figure out the way on php way to do this, or any other short way.

Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made that unnecessarily complex.

If you use the syntax `name="field[]"` then you will receive an array of values in $_POST['field'] like this :-

```
<form method="post" >
<ul>
   <li>Title: <input type="text" name="title[]" />
      <ul>
         <li>name: <input type="text" name="name[]" /></li>
         <li>decription: <input type="text" name="description[]" /></li>
         <li>Qty<input type="text" name="qty[]" /> 
             price: <input type="text" name="price[]" /></li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
         <li>name: <input type="text" name="name[]" /></li>
         <li>decription: <input type="text" name="description[]" /></li>
         <li>Qty<input type="text" name="qty[]" /> 
             price: <input type="text" name="price[]" /></li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
         <li>name: <input type="text" name="name[]" /></li>
         <li>decription: <input type="text" name="description[]" /></li>
         <li>Qty<input type="text" name="qty[]" /> 
             price: <input type="text" name="price[]" /></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
<input type="hidden" name="submit" value="haha">
<button>submit</button>
</form>
```

Now if you look at a var_dump or better still a print_r($_POST) you will see that data arrives to the PHP script in a nicely processible order.

So now you process them for example something like this

```
foreach ($_POST['name'] => $idx => $name ) :

    echo $name;
    echo $_POST['description'][$idx];
    echo $_POST['qty'][$idx];
    echo $_POST['prince'][$idx];

endforeach;
```

Comment: thanks riggs, can u show the way use php to handle these data?

Comment: You forgot to make `<input multiple='multiple' />` in your HTML. Obviously you loop over them: `foreach($_POST['description'] as $value){/* $value is value */}`